# How to keep css animation in sync with react effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, css-animations

I am trying to create a React component that shows a circular countdown line with a periodic text timer beside it. So the circle should countdown over 30 seconds and the text should show 5-4-3-2-1-0, 5-4-3-2-1-0, etc.

However, the text and CSS animation are out of sync so the circle timer ends in between the text cycles.

**CSS**

```
.animation {
  animation: countdown 30s linear infinite forwards;
}
```

**React Component**

```
const [reset, setReset] = useState(props.reset);
const [period, setPeriod] = useState(props.period);
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(reset);
const [runTime, setRunTime] = useState(0);

const circle = useRef<SVGCircleElement>(null);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  circle.current?.classList.add(css.animation);

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds((seconds) => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        return seconds - 1;
      } else {
        return reset;
      }
    });
  }, 1000);

  // Check total time
  setRunTime((runTime) => runTime + 1);
  if (runTime === period * 60) {
    clearInterval(this);
    setFeedback('Complete');
    circle.current?.classList.remove(css.animation);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [seconds]);

return (
  <>
    <svg className={css.svg}>
      <circle ref={circle} r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
    </svg>
    <p id={css.countdownNumber}>{seconds}</p>
  </>
);
```

Is the computation in the `useLayoutEffect` hook delaying each cycle?

How can I keep these two timers in sync?

Comment: Animating via JS would be my recommended approach. Timing CSS and JS would be quite tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using svg for your circle, use `strokeDasharray` with `strokeDashoffset` to fill the circle's border.

Create a `useEffect` block that is triggered by seconds, and calls a `setTimeout` to set tick the seconds count, and use the remainder operator to get the countdown. Now you can calculate the circumference to animate the border.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = ({ max, width, height, radius }) => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSeconds(s => s + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [seconds, max]);
  
  const countdown = seconds % (max + 1);
  
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  const offset = (max - countdown) / max * circumference;

  const cx = width / 2;
  const cy = height / 2;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{countdown}</div>
      
      <svg width={width} height={height}>
        <circle
          className="animation" 
          r={radius} 
          cx={cx}
          cy={cy}
          fill="none" 
          strokeDasharray={circumference}
          strokeDashoffset={offset}>
        </circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo max={5} width={200} height={200} radius={50} />);
```

```css
.animation {
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```